# How to save the output of a function?

Tags: javascript, html, function

I have a site that has a circle that changes color randomly when you click on it.

```js
var letter = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];

function color() {
  lineOfLetters = letter[Math.floor(Math.random() * 15)] + letter[Math.floor(Math.random() * 15)] + letter[Math.floor(Math.random() * 15)] + letter[Math.floor(Math.random() * 15)] + letter[Math.floor(Math.random() * 15)] + letter[Math.floor(Math.random() * 15)];
  var colorNumber = "#" + lineOfLetters;
  return colorNumber;
}

var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var radius = 250

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(300, 300, 250, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false)

function fillCircle() {
  ctx.fillStyle = color();
  ctx.fill()
}
document.write(color())
```

```css
.button {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 58px;
  top: 58px;
}
```

```html
<body onload="fillCircle()">
  <div onclick="fillCircle()" class="button"></div>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="600">nope</canvas>

</body>
```

I the page to display exactly what color the circle is.

I tried:

```
document.write(color())
```

But that just generates another color value and is not related to the color of the circle at all.

How do get the page to display exactly what color the circle is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assign the result of `color()` to a variable and then put it into the DOM.

```js
var letter = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];

function color() {
  lineOfLetters = letter[Math.floor(Math.random() * 15)] + letter[Math.floor(Math.random() * 15)] + letter[Math.floor(Math.random() * 15)] + letter[Math.floor(Math.random() * 15)] + letter[Math.floor(Math.random() * 15)] + letter[Math.floor(Math.random() * 15)];
  var colorNumber = "#" + lineOfLetters;
  return colorNumber;
}

var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var radius = 250

var colorSpan = document.getElementById("colorCode");

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(300, 300, 250, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false)

function fillCircle() {
  var c = color();
  ctx.fillStyle = c;
  ctx.fill();
  colorSpan.textContent = c;
}
```

```css
.button {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 58px;
  top: 58px;
}
```

```html
<body onload="fillCircle()">
  <div onclick="fillCircle()" class="button"></div>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="600">nope</canvas>
Color code is <span id="colorCode"></span>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just show that generated color like this:

```
function fillCircle (){
    document.write( ctx.fillStyle = color() );
    ctx.fill();
}
```

But *document.write* should not be used here, you should rather add an html element e.g.:

```
 <span id="color" > </span>
```

So we can do this inside the code

```
const colorLabel = document.getElementById("color");

function fillCircle (){
    colorLabel.textContent = ctx.fillStyle = color();
    ctx.fill();
}
```

---

Sidenote: to get a 6 char hex string you can easily do:

```
const color = "#" + Math.floor( Math.random() * 16 ** 6 ).toString(16);
```

Comment: Yeah, I was just using document.write to test it out, I did end up doing it in an html element. Thanks for that sidenote!